# Extracting text from binary file like .exe/.dll etc using C++

Tags: c++

I want to parse the given binary files and extract the information (text) from that using C++.

What methods are available?

Comment: Are you referring to information stored in resource file like version, developer, copyright and description?

Comment: About what @MeanEYE told: in this case you can use ResourceHacker.

Comment: Everything including exposed functions, code as well as you told resource and meta information etc

Answer (score 3):

You might use [strings(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strings&sektion=1) to extract the strings of printable characters in files to a file or pipe, then process these lines. For example:

```
$ strings werl.exe
!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
Rich
.text
`.rdata
@.data
.rsrc
QRVh
Could not load module %s.
win_erlexec
Could not find entry point "win_erlexec" in %s.
Could not find key %s in section %s of file %s
Cannot find erlexec.exe
erts-*
\bin
erts-
```

To save this output to a file `out.txt`, you use redirection:

```
$ strings werl.exe > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scan for strings of printable characters - most bytes in a binary code are non-printable, so when there is and uninterrupted string of for example 6 or more printable characters, there is good chance it is real string value. Plus strings are often terminated with \0, so you can look for a string of printable characters terminated by \0.